# Neptune gremlin java traversing with hops

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

We have a model in neptune db for tag and entity relationship as follows:

Vertices - tags.

```
id
---
123454
123478
345678
435677
890890
727455
345588
....
....
```

```
id   | from   | to     | hash | score
---------------------------------------------
3455 | 123454 | 345678 | key1 | 2.4
3456 | 123454 | 123478 | key2 | 3.5
3457 | 345678 | 435677 | key2 | 3
3458 | 435677 | 435677 | key3 | 1
3459 | 123454 | 435677 | key4 | 4
3460 | 345678 | 890890 | key5 | 3.25
3461 | 890890 | 435677 | key6 | 1.5
3462 | 123454 | 727455 | key7 | 0.5
3463 | 123454 | 345588 | key8 | 0.75
```

From and to are in and out vertices (ids of tags).
Note that in the edges, 'hash' can have duplicate values.

We are programming in Java and using tinkerpop gremlin version 3.5 as the client.

Basically I'm trying to find the aggregated scores for between tags and entities using a max hop provided.

example request scenarios:

1. entity-entity:
   total score between entity hashes 'key1' and 'key2' with max hops 2
2. tag-tag:
   total score between tag ids '123454' and '435677' with max hops 1
3. tag-entity:
   total score between tag id '123454' and entity hash 'key1' with max hops 0 (direct)

I'm new to neptune/gremline and don't have a proper idea on how to do this. Have been referring to tinkerpop documentations without much progress.

an example of a query that I have done for scenario 3 is:

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> = graphTraversalSource.V(tagId).outE().has("hash", entityHash).valueMap().toList());
```

And then get the scores by iterating the list and sum them.
It works for direct, but not sure how to continue this for 1 hop or 2 hops.

Also, this is for tag-entity only. Haven't managed to do the tag-tag or entity-entity scoring.

Any ideas on modelling these queries would be really helpful.
Many thanks!

Comment: Is the question mainly about how to perform a `repeat...until` type of query? If yes I can provide some examples using the Gremlin `repeat` step. Will the queries always need to explicitly traverse some number of hops like 1,2,3 etc. or will they sometimes need to keep going until they hit a leaf node? The key Gremlin steps for this type of query are `repeat`, `until`, `times` and `loops`.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Hi Kevin, thanks for your reply. The queries are for a given number of hops only, no need to go until the leaf is hit. 

Also, the question is also about modelling queries.
Eg: For scenario 1 in the question, the query is between two entities. 
Since entities (edges) are connected via tags (vertices),  the logic in my mind is:
- find the tags associated with each entities
- then apply those tags to 'from' and 'to' properties of the edges accordingly 
- apply required hops
- get the matching edges and calculate the score

Not sure how to translate this into a query.

Comment: It's interesting that your data model seems to be somewhat edge centric, with the main properties of interest being on the edges. Is it intended that the fourth edge has the same from and to node? Also is hash intended to be a property or could it instead not be used for the edge label?

Comment: I added the steps to create the sample graph below as well as some sample queries. While doing this it feels like the data model you have may make the queries for questions you want to answer harder to write than they would be with some data model changes. For example computing the score between hashes, becomes a lot simpler if those values are stored on vertices. Most `repeat` `until` type queries start and end with a vertex and not an edge.

Comment: Thanks @KelvinLawrence. Hash could be the edge label but this is the data model we have at the moment from the external party, so unfortunately we are unable to alter it. Same goes with switching hashes (entities) to vertices. Having said that, even if we switch the hashes to vertices, still we would have the same issue for other scenarios right? For example calculating the relationship between tags which would be edges after the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps can be used to build a sample graph based on the data provided.

```java
g.addV('tag').property(id,123454).as('t1').
  addV('tag').property(id,123478).as('t2').
  addV('tag').property(id,345678).as('t3').
  addV('tag').property(id,435677).as('t4').
  addE('link').from('t1').to('t3').property(id,3455).property('hash','key1').property('score',2.4).
  addE('link').from('t1').to('t2').property(id,3456).property('hash','key2').property('score',3.5).
  addE('link').from('t3').to('t4').property(id,3457).property('hash','key2').property('score',3).
  addE('link').from('t4').to('t4').property(id,3458).property('hash','key3').property('score',1)
```

We can confirm the graph looks OK by rendering it using a graph-notebook

[image]

The query below can be used to show us the scores between nodes123454 and 435677. The `repeat` combines `until` with `loops` to check for a specific target, or reaching a given depth. The second `has` is necessary to make sure that we found the node we wanted and did not just hit the maximum depth.

```java
g.V(123454).
  repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasId(435677).or().loops().is(2)).
  hasId(435677).
  path().
    by(id).
    by('score')
```

When run, using the Gremlin Console, we can see the results

```java
gremlin> g.V(123454).
......1>   repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).
......2>   until(hasId(435677).or().loops().is(2)).
......3>   hasId(435677).
......4>   path().
......5>     by(id).
......6>     by('score')

==>[123454,2.4,345678,3,435677]
```

All that remains is to extend the query to compute the total score. The `sack` step is useful for this.

```java
gremlin> g.withSack(0).
......1>   V(123454).
......2>   repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('score').inV().simplePath()).
......3>   until(hasId(435677).or().loops().is(2)).
......4>   hasId(435677).
......5>   sack()

==>5.4
```

With these building blocks you should be able to create the queries to answer each of the scenarios.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the detailed answer. I had tried to understand the solution, got a couple of questions on this:
1. I had provided only some sample data. When I do an outE() count on our db for a tag, it returns be around 4k. I wanted to check whether line 2 and 3 goes through all 4K edges and corresponding inV()s before going to the next level?
2. The idea is to calculate the total score for all possible paths within the given levels, but I think line 3 would terminate the loop when a match is hit, isnt it? so the other possible paths won't be considered right?

Comment: I had added 5 more edges to the original question to give the graph some data related to my comment above. With these 5 added edges, node 123454 has 3 paths to node 435677 with direct, 1 level and 2 levels. I added two extra edges to 123454 to show that there can be unrelated edges as well. With this dataset, scores between nodes 123454 & 435677 with 0 hops (direct) should be 4, within 1 hop (direct + 1 hop) should be 9.4 (4 + 5.4). Within 2 hops it is  4 + 5.4 + 7.15. 
If we consider nodes 345678 & 435677, then direct is 0. Within 1 level is 4.75.
Could you please advice?

Comment: By default this should be a breadth first search so it will explore all nodes/edges at the current depth before moving on to the next one. Did the query in the answer work for your updated dataset? If not it would be useful to update the question using the sample graph shown in the answer as a building block. That makes testing these additional scenarios/questions a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Yes, it does BFS first. I had to find all possible paths from a node to another within the given number of hops. So I went with the path().by(id).by(score) query and run it separately for each hops and solved it. Thanks for all the details, it was really helpful :)